# htaccess general rewrite but skip images

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to include certain file extensions from being rewritten fi they dont exit.

(Image Types: `jpg|gif|png`)

Currenty I have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=1]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I would need to skip this is the request url ends in: `.gif/.jpg/.png`

Been looking everywhere.. but can't find out how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This basically says, filename doesn't end with gif jpg or png, and it isn't a file, and isn't a directory, then send it to index.php

Comment: I get the idea .. but the code above stil l not working ( trying to redirect no matter what... any insights ? Driving me crazy:/

Comment: ah, just tried it on mine... if say you do a request for www.example.com/images/someimage.jpg and the images folder doesn't exist, it doesn't work... To get it working replace the image check one with: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$, have updated my answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

I should have thought an additional `RewriteCond` on that list would suffice.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.jpg|\.gif|.png)$
```

Not forgetting the `[OR]` where necessary.